# Server should reply as binary packet to the client

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, binary, gps

I have a module that should send GPS location to my server. Below I describe how communication happens between module and server:

1. When the module connects to the server, module sends its IMEI.
2. If server accepts data, then should reply to module 01. Note that confirmation should be sent as binary packet. I.e. 1 byte 0x01.

I'm struggling at second step. Have tried various combination, but neither worked.

```
client.puts('\x01')
client.send([0x01].pack("C"), 0)
client.write["01"].pack('H*')
```

Below is a full code example:

```
require 'socket'

class ClientThread
  def initialize(port)
   @server = TCPServer.open(port)
  end

  def run
    puts "Started TCP Server"

    loop do
      Thread.start(@server.accept) do |client|
        2.times do |index|
          data = client.recv(8192)

          if index == 0
            client.send('\x01'.encode('utf-8'), 0) # RESPONSE TO DEVISE THAT SERVER IS READY TO ACCEPT DATA 
          elsif index == 1
            puts self.log("Done! Closing Connection")
            client.close
          else
            client.send('\x00'.encode('utf-8'), 0) # RESPONSE TO DEVISE THAT SERVER IS NOT READY TO ACCEPT DATA
          end

        end # end of loop twice
      end # end of Thread
     end # end of infinite loop
    end # run method
   end # end of class

  new_thread = ClientThread.new(65432)
  p new_thread.run
```

Device does not understand that server is ready to accept data. Most likely, because binary packet is formed incorrectly. How do you form response, so device would understand to send GSP data?

Ask me please if any questions. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using TCP, why write your own handshake protocol?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I'm following communication protocol given by the Teltonika https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/Teltonika_Data_Sending_Protocols#Codec_8

Comment: Fair enough, but `If server accepts data, then should reply to module [0x]01.` seems like it's basically an ACK sequence, or the equivalent of an HTTP server response. In either case, if you don't want to leave it to a lower-level protocol, I suspect that you should be treating your packet pairs as separate objects with some control flow rather than indexing into them, especially in threads where you aren't using Thread-local variables. Just my $0.02 about a protocol I know little about. YMMV.

Comment: Re: "Device does not understand that server is ready to accept data." can you be more specific, please? Does the device produce an error? What data does the device receive, exactly? Also, for the sake of this question, would it be possible to simplify your code by removing the multi-threading?

Comment: @JaredBeck I appreciate you support. I have solved it, posted answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work.
Instead of `client.send('\x01'.encode('utf-8'), 0)` I have used `client.puts [0x01].pack("C")` and module started to send data.

Below is a full working example for Teltonika FMT100.

1. Module sends its IMEI to the server.
2. Server accepts data and replies as binary packet 0x01.
3. Module send GPS data to the server. At this point you will need to decode data.

   ```
    require 'socket'

    class ClientThread
     def initialize(port)
      @server = TCPServer.open(port)
      @imei = "unknown"
     end

     def log(msg)
      "#{Time.now.utc} #{msg}"
     end

    def run
      puts self.log("Started TCP Server")

    loop do
      Thread.start(@server.accept) do |client|
        if client
          2.times do |index|
            begin
              data = client.recv(8192)

              if index == 0
                @imei = data
                p self.log("Device Authenticated | IMEI: #{@imei}")
                client.puts [0x01].pack("C")
              elsif index == 1
                p data.unpack('H*').first
                p self.log("Done! Closing Connection")
                client.close
              else
                client.puts [0x00].pack("C")
              end

            rescue IOError
              p self.log("Stream is already closed")
            end
          end # end of loop twice

        else
          p self.log('Socket is null')
        end # if conditional
      end # end of Thread
    end # end of infinite loop
    end # run method
    end # end of class

    new_thread = ClientThread.new(65432)
    p new_thread.run
   ```

You should get something similar to:

```
"2021-12-30 11:12:22 UTC Device Authenticated | IMEI: \u0000\u000F357544374597827"
"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"
"2021-12-30 11:12:24 UTC Done! Closing Connection"
```